# Make navigation bar title clickable Objective C iOS 10.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Is there any way to make the navigation bar title clickable? I don't have any specific class for navigation bar. I control everything from ViewController. If there's a way, I would love to know. I have been searching it for quite a white but couldn't find a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make button on Navigation bar

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(btnclick:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64.0);

self.navigationItem.titleView =button;

-(void)btnclick:(id)sender
{ NSLog(@"button click");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way

```
UIView *topView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

UIButton * button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setTitle:@"Title here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button sizeToFit];

[topView addSubview:button];

[topView sizeToFit];

self.navigationItem.titleView = topView;

-(void)buttonAction:(Id) sender
{

 NSLog(@"button clicked");

}
```